# Перенаправление на index.php четыре раза

Tags: php

При переходе на index.php скрипт выполняется четыре раза. Уже все варианты в интернете перепробовал, не помогает.

В файле .htaccess прописано следующее[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В файле index.php код такой. Соединение с БД и добавление записи.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но скрипт выполняется 4 раза[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему перенаправление происходит 4 раза вместо одного?

Comment: Второй запрос ищет favicon и не находя стучится на `index.php`.

Comment: Почему на 4 раз, скрипт завершается?
Где он находит  favicon  после 4 раза?

Comment: Добавил favicon для страницы. Теперь вместо 4 сократилось до двух перенаправлений.
Какие будут предложения?

Comment: Теперь надо открыть мануал и понять что делает `pdo->query` и что делает `statement->execute`.

Comment: Точно, спасибо.
Долго сижу уже. Я выполняю два раза вставку (query и execute)
Вопрос закрыт